# WP7 - Adding Settings page. Reading values from a different page?

Tags: windows-phone-7, save, settings

So I've created a page called "Settings". Obviously in this page is where the settings are for the app. In the Settings page I've added 2 ToggleSwitches and 1 Listpicker. Using the Nokia Developer website on basics of Saving and reading Settings i managed to pull it off so it saves the states of the toggleswitches and listpicker.

The problem i'm having right now is that i need a way to read these saved setting values on the first page when the app starts so it can prepare the app accordingly. Soo far this is what i have in the Settings page:

```
Imports System.IO.IsolatedStorage
Partial Public Class Settings
Inherits PhoneApplicationPage
Private AppSettings As IsolatedStorageSettings
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    AppSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings
    ListPicker1.Items.Add("Saved Notes")
    ListPicker1.Items.Add("Important")
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As NavigationEventArgs)
    Try
        Tg1.IsChecked = CBool(AppSettings("UseAccentColor"))
        Tg2.IsChecked = CBool(AppSettings("GoBack"))
        ListPicker1.SelectedIndex = CByte(AppSettings("StartListFalse"))
    Catch ex As KeyNotFoundException
        AppSettings.Add("UseAccentColor", False)
        AppSettings.Add("GoBack", False)
        AppSettings.Add("StartListFalse", False)
        AppSettings.Save()
    End Try
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedFrom(e As NavigationEventArgs)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exiting, so save now")
    AppSettings("UseAccentColor") = Tg1.IsChecked
    AppSettings("GoBack") = Tg2.IsChecked
    AppSettings("StartListFalse") = ListPicker1.SelectedIndex
    AppSettings.Save()
End Sub
End Class
```

So soo far it saves on exit but i need a way to load these from startup i.e. my MainPage. Like a way to refer to this page and according to these settings change whatever needs to be changed.

How can i do this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You managed to save Settings to IsolatedStorage, and IsolatedStorage is accesssible from any page of your application. So in MainPage, just read those setting from IsolatedStorage instead of the Settings Page.

**EDIT :**
You can do it just like in OnNavigatedTo method in Settings Page

```
Private AppSettings As IsolatedStorageSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings
'Tg1.IsChecked is analog with useAccentColor
Dim useAccentColor As Boolean = CBool(AppSettings("UseAccentColor"))
'Tg2.IsChecked = goBack
Dim goBack As Boolean = CBool(AppSettings("GoBack"))
'ListPicker1.SelectedIndex = startListFalse
Dim startListFalse As Byte = CByte(AppSettings("StartListFalse"))
```

Comment: do you have any idea how i can do this? because when i tried to put the code in the MainPages onnavigated event i got soo many 'not declared because the controls are in different page.

Comment: I added some code (i'm not very fluent in VB though). The settings read from IsolatedStorage, and stored in variables. Then you can prepare the app accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for that but now that i've added that code to the mainpage how will i know whether the togglswitch(Tg1,Tg2) is actually checked? I added: ` Dim mp = TryCast(DirectCast(Application.Current, App).RootFrame.Content, Settings)
        If mp.Tg1.IsChecked = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButton.OK)
        End If ` but i seem to get a null refrence error. I just need to know whether the settings are actually applied. This is all added in the Mainpage's on navigated event. to check.

Comment: why you need to know that? togglswitch(Tg1,Tg2) is not even exist yet. Because Settings Page will not be created until you navigate to. And when you navigate to Settings Page, its OnNavigatedTo() method will be invoked. And when invoked, it will set Tg1, Tg2 according to the settings saved. You dont need to take care of Settings page in MainPage.

Comment: Basically I'm making a settings page. So if the toggleswitch is on then the app will do something. Now, for the app to know whether the toggleswitch is on or not i need a way to get that setting on the mainpage. do you know what i mean?

Comment: Yes i know. So how about this: if useAccentColor = true, mean Tg1 is checked (or actually will be checked when you navigate to Settings Page).

Comment: Yes! Kudos! to you my good member :) that's exactly what i need. Btw any idea where i can find out about wide tiles for windows phone 7.8 and adding them to my app? i want a pin to start functionality :D